# How use generic for object in TS?

Tags: typescript

I have function that use some generic inside, and choose data from object by key.
Is it possible use generic inside type of this object? or we need to create function for options for this?

```
enum Types {
  book = 'book',
}

type Base = {
    config: any
}

type Options<T> = {
    title: string,
    config:T
}

// How pass generic Desired from getBooks into options here?
const options: Record<Types, Options<??>> = {
  book: [{title:'title', config: ['some data']}]
}

const getBook = <Desired extends Base>(type: Types) => {
      return options[type]
}


getBook(Types.book)
```

Comment: Your object `options` is not of this type - the object in the array lacks a `config` property. Please clarify your question by editing it.

Comment: @kaya3 Updated object, the question is how use generic for such cases for object, is it possible or we need to create function?

Comment: What is "generic" about your object? What do you want to do that isn't achieved by just writing `string[]` in place of your `??`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's go by the object you wrote and pick the type apart definition by definition.

```
{                      // object
  book: [              // Record<Type, Array< ? >>
    {                  // Record<Type, Array<object>
      title: 'title',  // Record<Type, Array<Options< ? >>
      config: [        // Record<Type, Array<Options<Array< ? >>>
        'some data'    // Record<Type, Array<Options<Array<string>>>
      ]  
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also write this as `Record<Types, Options<string[]>[]>` but with the `[]` so close to each other I'd personally prefer to write it this way `Record<Types, Array<Options<string[]>>>`.

Alternatively one could read these arrays as a tuple with a single entry, then the type would be `Record<Types, [ Options<[string]> ]>` but I'm not sure if that was your intention.

Comment: Oh, thank you, but the question is whether we can use Desired generic for options something like this
const options: Record<Types, Options<Desired>>